How to Efficiently Handle Asynchronous API Requests in Python with Rate Limiting
I am trying to use the requests_futures library in Python to make asynchronous API requests to the Woosmap API for geocoding information based on a DataFrame that contains ZIP codes and country codes. My goals are:

To send no more than 50 requests per second to adhere to API rate limits.
Log detailed information about each request, including when a batch of 100 requests has been sent and how long it took.
Log failed requests or when no results are returned by the API.

Here is my current implementation:
df = random_df  

# Set your API key
API_KEY = "woos-***"

# Variables for request tracking and timing
request_counter_1 = 0
request_counter = 0
requests_this_second = 0
last_time_checked = time.time()
start_time = time.time()
# Initialize session
session = FuturesSession()


def response_hook(resp, *args, **kwargs):
    """Hook function for handling completion of each future."""
    if resp.status_code != 200:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve data for request with params {resp.request.params}: Status {resp.status_code}")

def get_geocode_info(row):
    global request_counter,request_counter_1, requests_this_second, last_time_checked, start_time

    # Check time and manage request rate
    current_time = time.time()
    if current_time - last_time_checked >= 1:  # More than one second has passed
        requests_this_second = 0
        last_time_checked = current_time
    
    while requests_this_second >= 50:  # If we've hit the rate limit
        time.sleep(0.1)  # Brief pause to avoid hitting the rate limit
        current_time = time.time()
        if current_time - last_time_checked >= 1:
            requests_this_second = 0
            last_time_checked = current_time

    url = "https://api.woosmap.com/localities/geocode"
    params = {
        "address": row['ZIPCODE'],
        "components": f"country:{row['COUNTRY_CODE']}",
        "key": API_KEY
    }
    headers = {'Referer': 'http://localhost'}
    future = session.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, hooks={'response': [response_hook]})
    requests_this_second += 1
    request_counter += 1
    request_counter_1 +=1
    if request_counter % 100 == 0:
        print(f"Number of requests sent: {request_counter}")
        end_time = time.time()
        time_taken = end_time - start_time
        print(f"Time taken for last 100 requests: {time_taken} seconds")
        start_time = time.time()
    
    return future

# Send asynchronous requests
futures = df.apply(get_geocode_info, axis=1)

# Collect responses
results = []
for index, future in futures.iteritems():
    response = future.result()
    if response.status_code == 200:
        json_data = response.json()
        if 'results' in json_data and json_data['results']:
            result = json_data['results'][0]
            flag = 1 if str(df.at[index, 'ZIPCODE']) == result.get('name', '') else 0
            results.append({
                'wm_address': result.get('formatted_address', ''),
                'wm_latitude': result['geometry']['location']['lat'],
                'wm_longitude': result['geometry']['location']['lng'],
                'wm_country': next((comp['long_name'] for comp in result['address_components'] if 'country' in comp['types']), ''),
                'wm_flag': flag
            })
            #print(f"Request #{request_counter}: Success for ZIPCODE {df.at[index, 'ZIPCODE']}")
        else:
            results.append({'wm_address': '', 'wm_latitude': None, 'wm_longitude': None, 'wm_country': '', 'wm_flag': 0})
           # print(f"Request #{request_counter}: No results found for ZIPCODE {df.at[index, 'ZIPCODE']}")
    else:
        results.append({'wm_address': '', 'wm_latitude': None, 'wm_longitude': None, 'wm_country': '', 'wm_flag': 0})
        print(f"Request #{request_counter}: Failed to retrieve data for ZIPCODE {df.at[index, 'ZIPCODE']} with status {response.status_code}")

# Create DataFrame from results and merge it with the original DataFrame
results_df = pd.DataFrame(results, index=df.index)
df = pd.concat([df, results_df], axis=1)

# Printing the DataFrame to verify results
df


Issues:
The asynchronous request handling does not properly adhere to the rate limit of 50 requests per second.
Number of requests sent: 100
Time taken for last 100 requests: 1.0169172286987305 seconds
Number of requests sent: 200
Time taken for last 100 requests: 2.0078818798065186 seconds
Number of requests sent: 300
Time taken for last 100 requests: 2.0065624713897705 seconds



How can I enforce a rate limit effectively with FuturesSession?

What is the best practice for accessing request parameters in the response hook to handle errors and no-results scenarios?

How can I ensure DataFrame updates align correctly with their respective asynchronous responses?


Thank you for any insights or suggestions you can provide!

Focus on a single specific problem. And do a preliminary debugging and ask a specific question with a [mre] and debugging details. In your implementation of updating the requests_this_second variable is completely wrong. You should not reset it to 0 when some time passed. Instead, decrement it when a request finished.
