How to efficiently send 500,000 requests to Woosmap API for geocoding using multiprocessing in Python?
I need to geocode a large dataset using the Woosmap API. I have a DataFrame containing around 500,000 addresses that I need to geocode as quickly as possible. Currently, I'm using the requests library to send requests one by one, but it's taking a significant amount of time. I've heard about multiprocessing in Python and I'm wondering how I can leverage it to speed up this process. Can someone provide guidance or a code example on how to send these requests concurrently using multiprocessing?
Current Approach:
import requests

url = "https://api.woosmap.com/localities/geocode?address=Place%20Jeanne-d'Arc&components=country%3AFR&key=YOUR_PUBLIC_API_KEY"

payload={}
headers = {
    'Referer': 'http://localhost'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)


I appreciate any help or suggestions on how to optimize this process for faster geocoding of my dataset and getting the final response in a dataframe. Thanks

"I've heard about multiprocessing" is insufficient knowledge to ask a proper question on StackOverflow. If you think that multiprocessing is the way to go, try researching how to do it and try it. Come here when you have an attempt to implement it and it didn't work.

@YevhenKuzmovych my bad  :) I did but no one replied so I thought to give a base question and maybe it helps others to start supporting ;)
https://stackoverflow.com/q/78420403/15452168

@YevhenKuzmovych with due respect, if you can't help me on the other ticket, please please please don't close this one? my issue will get lost without response then :( Thanks

I understand the frustration of not getting the response. I genuinely want to help you get help. Your questions suffer from a lack of focus. Please refer to [ask]. A perfect way to ask a question is also to include [mre] (that is complete without any unrelated parts). In your previous question, you have a lot of unrelated code, at the same time your code is not reproducible (no imports, no sample of data). This question doesn't include attempts to implement multiprocessing, so it looks like you're asking about basics that are covered on StackOverflow (or elsewhere) extensively.

The bad answer:
The most efficient way would be if the targeted API supports bulk requests and answers. Instead of making 0.5M requests, you would do 1 request and get all the answers. This is a bad answer since it depends on the API and doesn't solve your problem
The unsatisfying answer:
RTM and apply https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers
Doesn't come with a click-to-try solution but the example is close to what you need. Be prepared for the API you are calling to throttle your requests. A lot of services frown upon getting rapid-fire-queried since the server has to allocate resources for each incoming request

Looking at this other question you posted, I will assume that your are limited to 50 requests per second, which is a fairly generous allowance. This is equivalent to 1 request per .02 seconds. So if each request could be completed in less than .02 seconds, you would not even need to use multiprocessing or multithreading (the latter being the more appropriate since you are spending almost all of your time waiting for a network request to complete) and all you need is the ability to "throttle" you calls to make sure you are not calling the API too frequently. But if each call took .2 seconds (10 times longer than .02 seconds), then you would want a thread pool with at least 10 threads to ensure you are getting your maximum throughput while ensuring that you are not exceeding the allowed rate. There is no problem in having too many threads since we will be throttling the calls to the API:
"""Throttle an action."""

from collections import deque
from threading import Lock
import time

class RateLimiter:
    def __init__(self, number_of_actions: int, period: float):
        """
        Perform no more than number_of_actions actions in period seconds.
        """

        self._number_of_actions = int(number_of_actions)
        if self._number_of_actions != number_of_actions or number_of_actions < 1:
            raise ValueError('number_of_actions must be an integer >= 1')
        if period <= 0.0:
            raise ValueError('period must be > 0.0')
        self._period = period
        self._called_timestamps = deque()
        self._lock = Lock()

    def throttle(self):
        with self._lock:
            while True:
                now = time.monotonic()
                while self._called_timestamps:
                    time_left = self._called_timestamps[0] + self._period - now
                    if time_left >= 0:
                        break
                    self._called_timestamps.popleft()
                if len(self._called_timestamps) < self._number_of_actions:
                    break
                time.sleep(time_left)
            self._called_timestamps.append(now)

def worker(rate_limiter):
    """Here the throttling is done within the function as close
    to the actual action as possible for better control of the
    action rate."""

    rate_limiter.throttle()
    # Perform the throttled action:
    t = time.time() # The time the actions is called:
    # The simulated action taking approximately .2 seconds:
    time.sleep(.2)
    return t


def main():
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
    from itertools import repeat

    # We will simulate 500 "calls" to our API. With an allowed rate
    # of 50 calls per second (1 call per .02 seconds).
    # This should take approximately 10 seconds to complete.

    # The minimum number of threads required is time_per_call / allowed_calls_per_second:
    # or .2 / .02 = 10
    # Use more than 10 threads to cover additional overhead in worker
    with ThreadPool(15) as pool:
        rate_limiter = RateLimiter(50, 1.02)  # to be conservative
        start_time = time.time()
        time_stamps = sorted(pool.imap_unordered(worker, repeat(rate_limiter, 500)))
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time # also includes negligible sorting time
        for i, ts in enumerate(time_stamps[:20]):
            print(i, ts)
        print('...')
        for i, ts in enumerate(time_stamps[480:], start=480):
            print(i, ts)

        print()
        print('Total elapsed time:', time.time() - start_time)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Prints:
0 1714913907.3693967
1 1714913907.3693967
2 1714913907.3693967
3 1714913907.3693967
4 1714913907.3693967
5 1714913907.3693967
6 1714913907.3693967
7 1714913907.3693967
8 1714913907.3693967
9 1714913907.3693967
10 1714913907.3693967
11 1714913907.3693967
12 1714913907.3693967
13 1714913907.3693967
14 1714913907.3693967
15 1714913907.5736933
16 1714913907.5736933
17 1714913907.5736933
18 1714913907.5736933
19 1714913907.5736933
...
480 1714913917.0573225
481 1714913917.0573225
482 1714913917.0573225
483 1714913917.0573225
484 1714913917.0573225
485 1714913917.0573225
486 1714913917.0573225
487 1714913917.0573225
488 1714913917.0573225
489 1714913917.0573225
490 1714913917.0573225
491 1714913917.0573225
492 1714913917.0573225
493 1714913917.0573225
494 1714913917.0573225
495 1714913917.2623
496 1714913917.2623
497 1714913917.2623
498 1714913917.2623
499 1714913917.2623

Total elapsed time: 10.154577255249023

Important Note
You probably want to be a bit conservative when you specify the rate given that the time.time function is not perfectly accurate. Even successive calls to time_ns can return the same value. So instead of specifying 50 actions per second maybe you want to try 50 actions per 1.02 seconds, as I have done above.
